# Get multiple JSON keypair values within a JSON object only if a specific keypair value matches iterable

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, iterable

I am trying to pull multiple json keyvalue data within any given JSON object, from a JSON file produced via an API call, for only the JSON objects that contain a specific value within a keyvalue pair; this specific value within a keyvalue pair is obtained via iterating through a list.  Hard to articulate, so let me show you:

Here is a list (fake list representing my real list) I have containing the "specific value within a keyvalue pair" I'm interested in:

```
mylist = ['device1', 'device2', 'device3']
```

And here is the json file (significantly abridged, obviously) that I am reading from my python script:

```
[
    {
        "name": "device12345",
        "type": "other",
        "os_name": "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise",
        "os_version": null
    },
    {
        "name": "device2",
        "type": "other",
        "os_name": "Linux",
        "os_version": null
    },
    {
        "name": "device67890",
        "type": "virtual",
        "os_name": "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard",
        "os_version": null
    }
]
```

I want to iterate through mylist, and for each item in mylist that matches the json keyvalue key "name" in the json file, print the values for 'name' and 'os_name'.  In this case, I should see a result where after iterating through mylist, device2 matches the 'name' key in the json object that contains {'name':'device2'}, and then prints BOTH the 'name' value ('device2') and the 'os_name' value ('Linux'), and then continues iterating through mylist for the next value to iterate through the json file.

My code that does not work; let us assume the json file was opened correctly in python and is defined as my_json_file with type List:

```
for i in mylist:
    for key in my_json_file:
        if key == i:
            deviceName = i.get('name')
            deviceOS = i.get('os_name')
            print(deviceName)
            print(deviceOS)
```

I think the problem here is that I can't figure out how to "identify" json objects that "match" items from mylist, since the json objects are "flat" (i.e. 'device2' in my json file doesn't have 'name' and 'os_name' nested under it, which would allow me to dict.get('device2') and then retrieve nested data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I did not understand your question clearly, but it appears you're trying to read values off of the list instead of the JSON file since you're looking at `i.get` instead of `key.get` when `key` is what actually contains the information.

And for the optimization issue, I'd recommend converting your list of devices into a set. You can then iterate through the JSON array and check if a given name is in the set instead of doing it the other way. The advantage is that sets can return if they contain an item in `O(1)` time, meaning it will significantly speed up the overall speed of the program to `O(n) where n = size of json array`.

```py
for key in my_json_file:
    if key.get('name') in my_list:
        deviceName = key.get('name')
        deviceOS = key.get('os_name')
        print(deviceName)
        print(deviceOS)
```

Comment: didn't realize I could use the "in" logic for if x in y...this works.  I assume the only change I would need to do to make this "optimized" would be to simply the if statement to "if key.get('name') in set(my_list)", yes?

Comment: That is correct, but since the condition is in a loop, conversion might take place multiple times. So if you can, it would be a better idea to convert it into a set beforehand.